# "ionic cordova build ios" not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am trying to buliding ios. When I run command "ionic cordova build ios", am getting following error:

```
1 error generated.

1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/nirajviveksheel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fjclxmuyhnzdcjfcpayfrfancqwm/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GCDWebServerDataRequest.o MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/GCDWebServerDataRequest.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/nirajviveksheel/Desktop/ionictest/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,MyApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,MyApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s Plus,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/nirajviveksheel/Desktop/ionictest/myApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/nirajviveksheel/Desktop/ionictest/myApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code 1).
```

please give me solution......

Comment: Run the same command with --verbose, like ionic cordova build ios --verbose maybe there is more output.

Comment: Please check solution to here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/run-build-always-fails-with-exit-code-1-even-on-success/90359/8

Comment: try running by opening project workspace (xcode workspace file in ios platform) and running and see if you get errors

Comment: Maby you're not in project directory when running command: ionic Cordova build ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes ionic/cordova projects get messed up and need to be recreated. 
Try:

```
ionic platform remove ios

ionic platform add ios
```

This typically resolves this kind of issue.

**EDIT**: If that doesn't work, sometimes this issue can be caused when there is a permissions issue with a plugin. You may have to manually remove the plugin and platform directories before recreating them.

For good measure, I suggest you also update your libraries:

```
sudo npm update -g cordova
sudo npm update -g ionic

rm -rf plugins/ platforms/

ionic platform add ios
ionic run ios
```

Comment: @RakeshWadbudhe I've edited my post with another suggestion; let me know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

This error is pretty much untraceable and mostly comes up when you change app your configs.

Follow this steps (These steps always works for me)

1> **Remove your app's Derived Data Folder.** (/Users/nirajviveksheel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)

2> Remove and Add platform iOS. (try to use ionic instead of cordova in these commands)

> ionic platform remove ios
>   ionic platform add ios
>   ionic build ios

Comment: i have not change anything.....i just created example project and then i added ios platform and tried to  build it ....but its not working

Comment: did you try the above steps. try this and then build your app if the above not works than tell me what's your xcode version but first try this steps.

Comment: after applying above command ,they are telling me to use cordova so i used "ionic cordova platform remove ios","ionic cordova platform add ios" and "ionic cordova build ios".....but still its not working.

Comment: did you remove the derived data folder before running the commands?

Comment: my xcode version is 7 ...so i removed it and installed latest version .....Now everything is working fine.....Thanks

Comment: Now same problem is coming again when trying to build project on mac which is already created in windows.....

Comment: this is a contant problem for me....it comes after every 1 week or so.....but I follow the above steps and get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because my xcode version is 7 and its too much old...so removed it and install latest one.
it will work